# Bug in tbb::concurrent_unordered_multimap? Entries get lost even if single-threaded

Tags: c++, hashmap, unordered-map, tbb

My understanding is that `tbb::concurrent_unordered_multimap` should behave like `std::unordered_multimap` if I am using only one thread. However, in this example, it does not:

```
#include "tbb/concurrent_unordered_map.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

struct myhash {
    size_t operator()(const int& a) const {
        return 1;
    }
};

int main() {
    tbb::concurrent_unordered_multimap<int, int, myhash> tbbidx;
    std::unordered_multimap<int, int, myhash> stdidx;

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        tbbidx.insert(std::make_pair(i % 10, i));
        stdidx.insert(std::make_pair(i % 10, i));
    }

    std::cout << "tbb size " << tbbidx.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "tbb count " << tbbidx.count(0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "std size " << stdidx.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "std count " << stdidx.count(0) << std::endl;
}
```

The result is this:

```
tbb size 100
tbb count 1
std size 100
std count 10
```

If I remove `myhash`, I get the correct result. The way I understand hashmaps, however, is that a horrible hash function should only affect the performance, not the correctness as long as the function returns the same value if `x==y`.

Comment: Also, if you do an ordered insert (`i / 10, i` instead of `i % 10, i`), everything is fine.

Comment: What happens if you declare `volatile size_t one = 1;` and `return one` instead of `return 1`?  I'm curious if something is being optimized away because all hashes are equal.

Comment: Doesn't change anything. Also, I compiled with `-O0`.

Comment: Update: After looking into the TBB code, I am quite sure that this is a bug with internal_equal_range and multimapping. Waiting for Intel to confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mdsl,

The problem is in `internal_insert()`.  The reason `i / 10` worked where `i % 10` did not was the order the items were inserted into the multimap, which is a symptom of the bug.  `internal_insert` did not do a key-equality comparison, so every insertion was at the end of the list (all the hashes were equal, so the method just walked to the end.)  When `i / 10` was used, all the 0 keys were inserted, then all the 1 keys, and so on.  `internal_equal_range` **does** check the equality of the keys, and would correctly find then end of the range.

Thank you very much for finding the bug.  I am adding a "degenerate hash" unit test, and I still have to figure why our validators didn't catch the out-of-order list.

Regards,
Chris

(Sorry I got the key equation wrong...)